# If в expect

Tags: expect

Всем привет!
У меня есть скрипт на **expect** которым я настраиваю коммутаторы D-Link так как в ручную это довольно затруднительно.
Вот сам скрипт:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set IP [lindex $argv 0]
set COMD1 [lindex $argv 1]
set COMD2 [lindex $argv 2]
set timeout -1 
spawn ping -c 2 -i 3 -W 1 $IP
spawn telnet $IP
match_max 100000
expect "*ser*ame:"
# Посылаем имя пользователя и ждем запроса пароля.
send "robot\r"
expect "*ass*ord:"
# Посылаем пароль и ждем приглашения ввода командного интерпретатора.
send "xxxxxxxxxxxx\r"
expect "*#"
send "create mcast_filter_profile profile_id 1 profile_name full_pool_iptv\r"
expect "*#"
send "$COMD1\r"
expect "*#"
send "$COMD2\r"
expect "*#"
send "save all\r"
expect "*#"
send "logout\r"
expect eof
```

Скрипт меня практически полностью устраивает, проблема в том что когда он натыкается на коммутатор который не заведен в **tacacs+** он встает колом (ждет появления "#").
У меня не как не получается добавить к скрипту if чтобы он после логина проверял что выводиться **"#"** или **"Fail!"** и если авторизация не прошла то попробовать другой логин пароль.
Я нашел решение на [**python**](http://habrahabr.ru/post/127748/) возможно ли это сделать на чистом **expect** не переписывая на **python**?

Comment: Сто лет не пользовал expect, но там был таймаут. 

Вот какой-то [пример](http://wiki.tcl.tk/11583)

    #!/usr/bin/expect  --
    set timeout 30
    spawn /usr/local/bin/scp -P 36000 user@ip:/data/myfile  /data1
    expect {           
        password: {
            send "password\r"
        } "yes/no)?" {
            send "yes\r"
            set timeout -1
        } timeout {
            exit
        } eof {
            exit
        }
    }


после гугления: `expect timeout example`.

Comment: Я немного не правильно выразился, мне надо после  
    
    expect "*ser*ame:"
    # Посылаем имя пользователя и ждем запроса пароля.
    send "robot\r"
    expect "*ass*ord:"
    # Посылаем пароль и ждем приглашения ввода командного интерпретатора.
    send "xxxxxxxxxxxx\r"

в зависимости от ответа коммутатора выполнять определенные действия, по вашей ссылке я не понял как вывод в переменную засунуть :(

Comment: @Izya, а Вы еще и `man expect` почитайте. Там полно примеров.

Comment: Блин везде лазил а в ман забыл посмотреть!  
Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

примеры использования условного оператора в скрипте, интерпретируемом программой *expect*, можно увидеть, например, в [`man expect`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html):

```
if {условие} {действия}
if {условие} {действия} else {действия}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё можно так:

```
set timeout 10
...
expect {"*#"                     {send "$COMD1\r"}
        "wrong pass"             {send "other_command"}
        "network is unreachable" {exit 251}
         timeout                 {exit 255}
}
...
set timeout -1
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).